# Regex Find Replace distinct parts of a string for a porting application

Tags: c#, regex

If I have a line of code:

```
String s = "\t\tgets(buf);";
```

and need to convert it to

```
s = "\t\tbuf";
```

What Regex pattern would I use in the `Regex.Replace()` method to get rid of 
`gets()` and leave behind `buf` assuming that `buf` is a random string. I would also like to preserve the other formatting characters etc that may exist in that string.

Apologies for editing the question.
I used:

```
s = Regex.Replace(s, "gets", "");
s = s.Replace("(", "").Replace(")", "").Replace(";", "").Replace(" ", "");
s += " = Console.ReadLine();";
```

But this wouldn't work if the line get(buf) was surrounded by some other parenthesis or
formatting like

```
s= "/rgets (buf)"; OR  s= "(gets (buf))/n";
```

So I would Ideally just want to just get rid of the gets() leaving behind 'buf' and the other content in the line as is and concat to it later.
Thanks

Comment: Show us the regex you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You [**read the documentation**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#substitutions). Then you write the appropriate regular expression.

```
string s  = "\t\tgets(buf);" ;
string s1 = Regex.Replace( s , @"^(\t\t)gets\(.+)\)(;)" , @"$1$2 = Console.Readline()$3" ) ;
```

One might note the `gets(3)` takes an arbitrary expression that evaluates to a `char*`. That expression is not necessarily going to be an identifier or something that can be used on the left side of an assignment (as it were, an `lval` in the C language).

Comment: Yep, thanks for pointing that out. I'm writing something to port a few C functions to C# so I've accounted for that.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use a couple methods from the string class to achieve this:

```
s = string.Concat(s.Replace("gets(", "").Replace(");", ""), " = Console.ReadLine();");
```

`Regex` is powerful, but can sometimes be overkill.

If you really feel you need it, then please add more details into your question.